# Joda time forPattern doesn't work correctly with 4-digit years

Tags: android, jodatime

Assume I have following parser with joda-time lib for android

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").parseDateTime(maybeDate);
```

My aim is to filter input in some editText with TextWatcher and try to parse input and check if it is a Date.

The following time passes this pattern, despite there are 4 "y" letters!

**06.12.1** (while I tried to put 06.12.1988)

P.S. appendYear(4,4) for formatter also fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This obeys the same rules as Java's [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits. So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12 A.D.

One option you may want to consider is formatting the value after parsing - if it doesn't round trip (i.e if the formatted value isn't the same as the original text), reject it as invalid.